# Convert this in validation expression driver's license numbers

Tags: asp.net, expression, validation, license-key

Hi I'm creating a registration page. It has "Enter License Number:" i want to create a validation expression that if the user type a wrong format in that field. The form will not be submitted. It must be corrected before they submitted. I dragged the "Regular Expression Validator" in my website. But they don't have a default expression for license number. I must custom the expression to have my own expression.

Now i only want to know what is the validation expression of this sample license number:

**G11-11-004064** -- A Philippines sample driver's license. 
 
 LetterNumberNumber - NumberNumber - NumberNumberNumberNumberNumberNumber

Could you convert it?

Comment: Please don't use all-caps. This is considered yelling at the reader. I corrected it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a regular expression editor. It's aimed towards Ruby but will do for .NET as well:

- http://rubular.com/

I don't know about the detailed specification of the license numbers you#re looking for, but I created a regex based on your example: `^[A-Z]\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{6}$`.

You can modify it here:

- http://rubular.com/r/7bHsX1tJ23

**The example explained:**

```
^[A-Z]\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{6}$
```

`^` = start of line

`[A-Z]` = a single upper case letter

`\d{2}` = any number with 2 digits

`\d{6}` = any number with 6 digits

`$` = end of line

If you want to make sure you don't miss lower case letters starting the license use `[A-Za-z]` instead of `[A-Z]`

(Thanks to Paul Sullivan)

Comment: Much better than mine Dennis (but add the regex to SO also so people can see it here :)

Comment: Thanks! :) the system told me that 8 minutes more before i can accept your answer :) I'll accept and vote it later. Thanks again.

Comment: I edited to explain the regex also Dennis and added lower case start letter (which will inevitably happen ;))

Comment: @PaulSullivan thanks for taking the time, I added some minor corrections.

Answer (score 2):

```
/[A-Za-z][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/
```

I'm sure this is as basic as it gets but it will match

see [online regex tested](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/regexp-editor.php)

Comment: Thanks!!! Working :) sadly 5 minutes more before i can accept your answers guys. I'll accept and vote it later. Thanks again.

Comment: I added a load of explanation to Dennis answer as it is more compact - mine is very basic and long winded

Comment: Sad. I can only vote one acceptable answer here? I want both of you to accept your answers. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Looks like OP likes yours better :-)

Comment: @PetersonPilares change the answer to Dennis' please mine is woefully lacking ;)

Comment: @DennisTraub respectfully asked OP to switch to your answer - only fair